# Multiple LCID error with SQL Server Full-text Index

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, sqlexception, lcid

Changing one full-text index column Language (LCID) to *Neutral* when the others are *English* results in the following error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904):
Full-text table or indexed view has more than one LCID among its
full-text indexed columns
```

Repopulating the index does not resolve the error.

If SQL Server lets me specify different Languages for every full-text column, then surely there must be a way to bypass this error?

Comment: Could you share the table schema and the options passed to full-text index creation please?

Answer (score 15):

You should check if all the columns that are full-text indexed have the same language word breaker. Go to context menu of the table--> Full text index--> Properties. In the left side, you'll find Columns. Select it and edit all language word breaker to be the same.
I hope you find this usefull

Comment: The context menu properties were greyed out for me. However I managed to change the language via the catalog properties dialog. In the database tree, under Storage > Full Text Catalog > right click on catalog and select Properties. Select Tables/Views page in left sidebar. Then select Table to update and then update "Language for" column in Selected object properties below.